# xlsx file doesn't exist when read inside for loop

Tags: r, excel, for-loop

I'm having an issue where my files don't exist when they enter my for loop and try to be read in.

```
for (file in file_names){ 
  file <- file.path(wd, file) 
  temp_data <- read.xlsx(file) ...
```

I get the error: Error in read.xlsx.default(file) : File does not exist.

I have tried other functions from other packages to read in excel files, this doesn't work.

However when I try reading in the data outside the for loop or I try this to check the files exist it works as it should.

```
for (file in file_names){ 
  file <- file.path(wd, file) 
  print(file) 
  exists <- file.exists(file) 
  print(exists) 
}
```

Returns TRUE

Does anyone have any ideas how I can fix this?

Note: this code use to work before either moving the files into onedrive (however reading in other files from onedrive works) or before adding a rproj file and setting this up as a git repository - so these might have triggered the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO.  IO can'r be definitive, not least because you haven't told us what `wd` is.  If you're obtaining your `file_names` using `list.files`, the simplest option may well be to include `full.names = FALSE` in the call to `list.files`.  Alternatively, the files may exist but you may (no longer) have read access to them.

Comment: I've seen many questions on SO in the [tag:r] tag with problems related to doing things on a onedrive (e.g., installing packages); while I haven't seen problems of reading a simple file from it, it is possible that something about how Windows is presenting the filesystem to processes such that R is a little confused. I'm stretching here, tbh, since even discarding that we don't have access to your drive, this question is lacking some detail. For instance, show contents of `wd` and `file` and the code (outside the loop) that works.